# Creating xlsx file using XSSFWorkbook, but getting error while using method createSheet("String")

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I have tried to include all the jars needed in Referenced Libraries.
There are similar questions on this forum, I have gone through all but unable to resolve the issue.

My Code Snippet:

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Gene");
        Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
```

[All the jars that I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaXNH.png)

I am getting following errors:

Exception stack trace:

```
  org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.createRelationship(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:602)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.createSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:896)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.createSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:807)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.createSheet(XSSFWorkbook.java:122)
        at DomParser.main(DomParser.java:18)
    Caused by: org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.newDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:111)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.createRelationship(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:587)
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.newDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:109)
        ... 5 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorksheetImpl.generatedSetterHelperImpl(Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;IS)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorksheetImpl.setColsArray(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper.cleanColumns(ColumnHelper.java:66)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.helpers.ColumnHelper.<init>(ColumnHelper.java:46)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentCreate(XSSFSheet.java:259)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.<init>(XSSFSheet.java:187)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Is that the complete stacktrace? I had used even less number of jar for something similar and it worked fine for me. [Jars used](https://imgur.com/a/67swgvo)

Comment: Please try with `xmlbeans-3.0.1` instead of `xmlbeans-5.1.3` and let us know if it helped.

Comment: Yes, that is complete stacktrace. I have included extra jars to avoid the errors, but had no luck, I just wanted to know that all my jars are compatible or not

Comment: Thank you Cos64. It worked. I had to remove xmlbeans-5.1.3 and use xmlbeans-3.0.1 instead. Could you please elaborate what was issue? Thank you once again

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ow2.jonas.osgi/xmlbeans/5.1.3 is not the official xmlbeans jar - it appears to be a copy of xmlbeans made in 2008.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `xmlbeans-3.0.1` instead of `xmlbeans-5.1.3`.

Starting from the error, which was:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorksheetImpl.generatedSetterHelperImpl(Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;IS)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;
```

I searched the Maven Central Repository for jars containing the class `CTWorksheetImpl`:
https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTWorksheetImpl

The answer was `poi-ooxml-schemas`, which you already had, and was the same version as `poi`. Seemed OK. Then I thought it had to be the method itself. The parameters were from the `org.apache.xmlbeans` package, so the `xmlbeans` version was probably wrong.

How can you find out the right version?

Rather than gathering jar files manually, you may want to try [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) for dependency management. In a Maven project, it would be enough to say you want `poi-ooxml`. This would automatically bring in all the dependencies, recursively, with the right versions.

This is an example Maven `pom.xml` file you could use your project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Even if you don't want to (or can't) use Maven in your project, you could at least do a separate project just for finding out the dependencies, like I did.

[image: Screenshot of dependencies]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.